# Lazy and Eager fetching in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, filter, hql, hibernate-mapping

How lazy fetching works by default in hibernate using XML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes of entity loading in hibernate **lazy** and **eager**. If you define entity configuration via XML mapping then **lazy** attribute is defined in the relationship tag(ie `many-to-one`, `one-to-many` etc.).

If you don't define lazy attribute then by default the lazy loading is enabled ie the value of lazy will be **true** but if you want eager loading then you need to turn off lazy loading by setting `lazy=false`.

Now if your `lazy=true` then select statement is executed whenever you try to access the child entities whereas if `lazy=false` (ie eager fetch is there), then you will notice that select query for child entities gets triggered immediately after the select query of parent entity.
(You can notice this behavior by turning showSql to true in your console logs.)

Hope it clear outs all your queries